# Is there a way to skip a test from inside the test? I.E. Skip Exception -> TestNGCitrusTestRunner

Tags: citrus-framework

Is it possible to skip a test, from within the test using TestNGCitrusTestRunner?

Basically, trying to use the AssumptionViolatedException, and SkipException from JUNIT/TestNG aren't working for me.

We query data from a database, then run a test, compare the test to the database. If the database has no data the test fails. Ideally, we would skip the test, since the test didn't really pass or fail.

I've tried

```
throw new AssumptionViolatedException("test");

throw new SkipException("Test");
```

Both exceptions cause a failure exception. Rather than skip the test

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the tests to skip using the following:

```
ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
```

This modifies the testNG and other reports output to skipped, but the Citrus report has the tests passing